# Extracting website data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract timetable data from [this site](https://www.snav.it). The content is contained in a div with class .departures-table. I want to ignore the first two rows and store the data in an array, but it's not working. I'm obviously making an error but can't figure which one. Thanks

```
    snav_live_departures_url = "https://www.snav.it/"
    headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.3'}
    request = urllib.request.Request(snav_live_departures_url,headers=headers)
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    snav_live_departures = []
    snav_live_departures_table = list(soup.select('.departures-table div')) [2:]
print(snav_live_departures_table)
for div in snav_live_departures_table:
    div = div.select('departures-row')
    snav_live_departures.append({
        'TIME':div[4].text,
        'DEPARTURE HARBOUR':div[0].text,
        'ARRIVAL HARBOUR':div[1].text,
        'STATUS':td[3].select('span.tt-text')[0].text,
        'PURCHASE LINK':div[6].select('a')[0].attrs['href']
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, when dealing with JavaScript heavy pages like this, you may want to monitor Network on your Dev Tools in your browser to see how data loaded.

This code will generate a beautiful dictionary for you to parse the data as you want:

```
import requests
import json

URL = 'https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/dashboard/nextDepartures?callback=jQuery12345&_=12345'

r = requests.get(URL)
s = r.content.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(s[16:len(s)-2])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different things going on here:

1. The **html** does not contain the data you want, it is loaded via a JavaScript callback, which one can easily see by looking at the output of the page source, and also seeing [their API call](https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/dashboard/nextDepartures?callback=jQuery12345&_=12345) in the developer tools
2. You actually were "lucky" there was no data in the page, otherwise this code would have exploded with `NameError` since `td` is not in scope:

   ```
       'DEPARTURE HARBOUR':td[0].text,
   ```
3. It's unclear what you were even trying do do with that line, since those children are not `<td>` elements anyway, they're all `<div>`s

I think you will likely be happiest just mimicking the API call, stripping the JS callback text off of the response, and using the structured data:

```
fh = urllib.request.urlopen(api_url)
js_text = fh.read().decode('utf-8')
fh.close()
json_text = re.replace(r"^[^(]+\(", "", re.replace(r"\);$", "", js_text))
data = json.loads(json_text)
```

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about that, since the call is also visible on line 1404 of [their app's script.js](https://www.snav.it/wp-content/themes/snav/asset/js/script.js). If you make a request to that API url I provided and get back the data that I said you would, then which story is more likely to be true?

Comment: or, heh, did you quite literally look for `jQuery1234` in the request list? because that name, along with the `_` cache busting parameter, is quite clearly dynamically generated

Comment: Thanks I'll mimic the API call. The td were just an issue with a copy and paste.